# No Basic authentication possible for Jira Rest API with R

Tags: r, rest, basic-authentication, jira-rest-api

I am currently despairing of the basic authentication of the Jira Rest API. Here is my example code:

```
  #username = jiraname and not the mailadd
  credentials <- "username:password"
  credentials <- base64_enc(credentials)
  header_auth <- paste0("Basic ",credentials)

  url <- "https://host/jira/rest/api/2/issue/ABC-123"

  res <- GET(url, add_headers(Authorization = header_auth), accept_json())

  parsed_json <- content(res, "parsed")
  parsed_json <- enframe(unlist(parsed_json, recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE))
```

That is just one example of what I tried...
The answer is always:

```
1 errorMessages1 Sie haben nicht die Berechtigung, den den Vorgang zu sehen. (You don't have the permission to see this issue)
2 errorMessages2                                      Anmeldung erforderlich (Login required)
```

I tried the same URL in my browser (where I am logged in obviously) and I get the expected result.

What am I doing wrong?

Greetings

EDIT:
Jira is running on an Apache Server. Is there anything to consider?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue in python. I was able to login through portal but not through jira API. In Jira API I was getting the error access denied.
Issue was the URL of JIRA. Through portal what I was using same URL I was putting in the API. The url was like this "https://asc/something", the issue gets solved when I change the URL to "https://asc-repo/something"in the API. 
Please cross check with you JIRA admin the URL for accessing through API.
Try URL like this "https://host-repo/jira/rest/api/2/issue/ABC-123

Comment: Ok thank you for this idea. I will check that on monday. What is the repo variable?

Answer (score 0):

To what I understand, you are using the wrong API to BASE64 encode the `username:password` string replaced with the actual credentials. As per the documentation, this is the correct API to use for `R`.

Documentation [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/base64enc/index.html) and [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base64enc/versions/0.1-3)

Using `base64enc` instead of `base64_enc` should solve your problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but actually it makes no difference with which package I encode my credentials.. The output is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The following script worked for me:
I created a token and used the token value as shown below.

The 'token.value' was the base64(txt) value which looked something like this "5asdfilkasdfioidsf123sdf"

```
txt = "username@email.com:password"
token <- base64(txt) 

system('curl -D- --header "Authorization: Bearer token.value" -X POST --data xx -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://somedomainname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/')
```